# Removendo elementos de uma lista

Tags: python

Estou tendo problemas com meu código.

```
print('inserindo e removendo itens da lista\n')

bom_dia = []

bom_dia.insert(0, 'python')
bom_dia.insert(1, 'a')
bom_dia.insert(2, 'b')

print(bom_dia)

print()


del bom_dia[0]
print(bom_dia)

del bom_dia[1] # 1
print(bom_dia)

del bom_dia[2] # 2
print(bom_dia)
```

1. Possui um *bug*, apagando o item 'b' e não 'a'
2. O item 2 simplesmente não é reconhecido

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver este problema?

Comment: Quando você remove a posição 0, a lista passa a ter dois valores: `'a'` na posição 0 e `'b'` na posição 1. Quando você remove a posição 1, estará removendo `'b'` e quando tenta remover a posição 2 dá erro, já que nessa hora a lista terá apenas `'a'` na posição 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lista é uma sequencia direta de valores, eles não ficam associados com o índice. Então, ao remover um elemento do meio da lista, todos os elementos à frente são  "deslocados".

Por exemplo, se você tem uma lista com 3 elementos `lista = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

- O elemento `0` é o `'a'` (`lista[0]`)
- O elemento `1` é o `'b'` (`lista[1]`)
- O elemento `2` é o `'c'` (`lista[2]`)

Ao remover o elemento `0` (com `del lista[0]`) a lista fica assim: `['b', 'c']`

- O elemento `0` agora é o `'b'` (`lista[0]`)
- O elemento `1` agora é o `'c'` (`lista[1]`)
- Não existe mais elemento `2`

Em seguida você remove o elemento `1` (com `del lista[1]`), a lista fica assim: `['b']`

- O elemento `0` agora é o `'b'` (`lista[0]`)
- Não existe mais elemento `1` nem `2`, a lista só tem um elemento

Finalmente, ao tentar remover o elemento `2` (com `del lista[2]`) você recebe o erro, pois a lista não tem mais o elemento `2`.

Uma forma comum de resolver esse problema é remover os elementos sempre ordenando de tras pra frente, ou seja, remover o elemento `2` primeiro, depois o `1` e finalmente o `0`, pois isso evita o deslocamento dos ítens que ainda vão ser removidos no futuro.